# CSS float: right

Tags: jquery, css

I have this part of HTML code:

```js
 function mostralogin() {
      $("#div-login").fadeToggle("fast");
    }
```

```css
    header {
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #ececec;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #b2b2b2;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #b2b2b2;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #b2b2b2;
      display: block;
    }
    #div-login {
      width: 200px;
      height: 180px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      border-radius: 8px;
      border: 3px solid #4F9D97;
      margin-left: 84%;
      margin-top: 48px;
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    #logintext {
      color: #4F9D97;
      font-size: 20px;
      float: right;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    #logintext:hover,
    #logintext:active {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #4F9D97;
    }
    #regtext {
      color: #4F9D97;
      font-size: 20px;
      float: right;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    #regtext:hover,
    #regtext:active {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #4F9D97;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <header>
      <a id="regtext"> REGISTRAZIONE </a>
      <a id="logintext" onclick="mostralogin()"> LOGIN </a>
      <form name="login" id="div-login" action="../PHP/login.php" method="post">
        ... (form stuffs) ...
      </form>
    </header>
```

When i click on the word Login it should appear as hidden form,everything is working, until i applied `float: right` on the css file at the `<a>` tags. By now the `mostralogin()` JQuery function and the `:hover` and `:active` things don't work anymore. Why does this happen?

Comment: It seems works. Where is the problem?

Comment: @humble.rumble I tried it right now, but it doesn't work neither in this way.

Update: i deleted the float: right and text-align: right/left and now it doensn't work anymore, even without anything... i'm going crazy

Comment: I try to delete `float: right` and It works. So, maybe I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Yeah i re-opened Dreamweaver and just without `float: right`, now it works. So i tried the humble.rumble solution and now it works.
But now the `margin-top 10 px;` doens't work anymore. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Btw, i putted the two `<a>` into a `<div>`, and i applied here the `margin-top`, now everything works. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution!
HTML part:

```
<header>
    <div id="textcont">
    <a id="logintext" onclick="mostralogin()"/>LOGIN</a>
    <a id="regtext" onclick="mostralogin()" />REGISTRAZIONE</a>
    </div>
    <form name="login" id="div-login" action="../PHP/login.php" method="post">
 ... (form stuffs) ...
    </form>
</header>
```

CSS part:

```
header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ececec;
    position: fixed;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #b2b2b2;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #b2b2b2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #b2b2b2;
    display: block;
    text-align:right;
}

#logintext {
    color:#4F9D97;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#logintext:hover, #logintext:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F9D97;
}

#regtext {
    color:#4F9D97;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-right: 20px;

}

#regtext:hover, #regtext:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F9D97;
}

#textcont {
margin-top: 10px;

}
```